# Get "SpatialTypeName" from DbGeography

Tags: leaflet, geospatial

I have a group of coordinates that should be a polygon but sometimes is a multipolygon and I need to check to see what it is:

```
if (DbGeography.FromText(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(json.Polygon.Value), srid).ToString(), srid)
                            .SpatialTypeName.Equals("Polygon"))
```

but my problem is that I get this error:

```
DbGeography.FromText(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(json.Polygon.Value), srid).ToString(), srid).SpatialTypeName   'DbGeography.FromText(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(json.Polygon.Value), srid).ToString(), srid).SpatialTypeName' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'    string {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
```

Part of the if

```
DbGeography.FromText(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(json.Polygon.Value), srid).ToString(), srid)
```

on watch is:

```
{SRID=4326;POLYGON ((-0.5504724383354187 51.379008223398628, -0.55046439170837391 51.379009897541955, -0.55100619792938232 51.378588011485647, -0.5504375696182251 51.378588011485647, -0.55017471313476562 51.379023290686426, -0.55046439170837391 51.379009897541955, -0.5504724383354187 51.379008223398628))}
```

but it cannot get `.SpatialTypeName` and I don't know what am I doing wrong